# golang memory explosion: newdefer

Tags: go, pprof

I have an program that listens on udp for log traffic, attempts to parse it, and then insert it into Redis. At a certain level of traffic, the memory seems to "explode" (Rapidly increase from a few hundred Megabytes to Gigabytes.

I've grabbed a heap profile shortly after this happens and it returns the following:

```
(pprof) top100 -cum
Total: 1731.3 MB
     0.0   0.0%   0.0%   1731.3 100.0% gosched0
  1162.5  67.1%  67.1%   1162.5  67.1% newdefer
     0.0   0.0%  67.1%   1162.5  67.1% runtime.deferproc
     0.0   0.0%  67.1%   1162.0  67.1% main.TryParse
     0.0   0.0%  67.1%    438.0  25.3% runtime.main
   301.5  17.4%  84.6%    437.5  25.3% main.main
   136.0   7.9%  92.4%    136.0   7.9% runtime.malg
     0.0   0.0%  92.4%    136.0   7.9% runtime.newproc
     0.0   0.0%  92.4%    136.0   7.9% runtime.newproc1
     1.5   0.1%  92.5%    131.3   7.6% main.RedisCuller
     0.0   0.0%  92.5%    108.5   6.3% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).Do
     0.0   0.0%  92.5%    108.5   6.3% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).readReply
     0.0   0.0%  92.5%    108.5   6.3% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*pooledConnection).Do
    95.8   5.5%  98.0%     95.8   5.5% cnew
     0.0   0.0%  98.0%     95.8   5.5% runtime.cnewarray
    34.0   2.0% 100.0%     34.0   2.0% runtime.convT2E
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.0% main.init
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.0% net/http/pprof.init
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.0% sync.(*Once).Do
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.0% syscall.Getenv
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.0% time.init
```

When the program is "healthy" the profile looks more like:

```
(pprof) top20 -cum
Total: 186.7 MB
     0.0   0.0%   0.0%    186.7 100.0% gosched0
     0.5   0.3%   0.3%    122.7  65.7% main.RedisCuller
     0.0   0.0%   0.3%    103.5  55.4% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*pooledConnection).Do
     0.0   0.0%   0.3%    103.0  55.2% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).Do
     0.0   0.0%   0.3%    103.0  55.2% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).readReply
    88.2  47.2%  47.5%     88.2  47.2% cnew
     0.0   0.0%  47.5%     88.2  47.2% runtime.cnewarray
     0.0   0.0%  47.5%     57.0  30.5% main.TryParse
    57.0  30.5%  78.0%     57.0  30.5% newdefer
     0.0   0.0%  78.0%     57.0  30.5% runtime.deferproc
    34.0  18.2%  96.3%     34.0  18.2% runtime.convT2E
     1.5   0.8%  97.1%      6.5   3.5% main.main
     0.0   0.0%  97.1%      6.5   3.5% runtime.main
     5.0   2.7%  99.7%      5.0   2.7% runtime.malg
     0.0   0.0%  99.7%      5.0   2.7% runtime.newproc
     0.0   0.0%  99.7%      5.0   2.7% runtime.newproc1
     0.0   0.0%  99.7%      0.5   0.3% bufio.NewWriter
     0.0   0.0%  99.7%      0.5   0.3% bufio.NewWriterSize
     0.0   0.0%  99.7%      0.5   0.3% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*Pool).get
     0.0   0.0%  99.7%      0.5   0.3% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*pooledConnection).get
```

The only defer I have in my code is surrounding the parsing function (since it can frequently fail):

```
    for {
            rlen, _, err := sock.ReadFromUDP(buf[0:])
            checkError(err) 
            raw := logrow.RawRecord(string(buf[:rlen]))
            go TryParse(raw, c)
    }

    ...

    func TryParse(raw logrow.RawRecord, c chan logrow.Record) {
        defer func() {
                if r := recover(); r != nil {
                        //log.Printf("Failed Parse due to panic: %v", raw)
                        return
                }
        }()
        rec, ok := logrow.ParseRawRecord(raw)
        if !ok {
                return
                //log.Printf("Failed Parse: %v", raw)
        } else {
                c <- rec
        }
}
```

Does anyone see anything obvious I am doing wrong that could cause memory to suddenly balloon? Or maybe provide some direction in pinning it down?

**Edit (More code around the logrow.Record Channel):**

```
c := make(chan logrow.Record)
...
go RedisInserter(c, bucket, retention, pool)

func RedisInserter(c chan logrow.Record, bucket, retention int, p *redis.Pool) {
        for rec := range c {
                logrow.SendToRedis(rec, bucket, retention, p)
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you closing `c` (`chan` of `logrow.Record`)? If so, are you deferring the closing of `c`? Not sure what else to suggest without seeing more code sorry.

Comment: @Intermernet: Added a little more code around that channel. I never close it because what "should" happen is that the channel is constantly being filled with logrows by the `go TryParse` and that `RedisInserter` loop should be consuming those rows. Looking at it now I could see that maybe logrow.SendToRedis could get blocked somehwere, and the channel fills up - but don't see how that would result in high newdefer memory usage?

Comment: There is a memory leak in a closure'd defer function. Which would be the case if you uncommented the printf.:
https://codereview.appspot.com/10784043/
Have you tried with tip?

Comment: @Aralo: The printf is commented out in the current version, so don't really being that the source. Also the memory increase happens pretty fast. Doing some higher resolution monitoring to try to find out how fast currently...

Comment: What do you send as parameter to `panic`? Isn’t that big?

Comment: @Mostafa: I never call panic

Comment: @Mostafa: What is happening is that tryparse is doing a bunch of string slicing, so the panic will happen inside of that due to the slice being out of bounds on the rawrecord. So maybe those raw records never get cleaned up or something?

Comment: @KyleBrandt I realized the `recover` is for index out of bound and other runtime panics when you said you never call panic, but can’t be sure about what’s causing the memory usage.

Comment: @Mostafa: Is actually dying right now, which I knew how to inspect memory with gdb :-/

Comment: FYI: `newdefer()` seems to be only called by `panic` (http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c#L23). Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @KyleBrandt what version of go are you using this with? It's probably worth it to at least try the 1.2RC that just came out (or even tip):
https://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list

Comment: @Aralo: go version
go version go1.1.1 darwin/amd64 and cross compiling for Linux, will try that out

Comment: @Aralo: Looks like you were right with the leak in the closure'd defer function (no crashes since rebuilding with go latest. If you answer I can give you your points :-)

Comment: @KyleBrandt I'm too lazy. Answer it yourself ;) Glad it's resolved for you! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a leak in closured deferred function (a problem in Go itself) as we see in:

```
    defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                    //log.Printf("Failed Parse due to panic: %v", raw)
                    return
            }
    }()
```

So rebuilding with the latest version of Go resolved the problem ( Reference: https://codereview.appspot.com/10784043/ ). However, the smart thing to do is to of course design the ParseRecordFunction so it doesn't end up trying to slice out of bounds and cause a panic.